# How to make a Win32 control created without WS_VISIBLE visible?

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

Suppose `hCtl` is a handle to a control created **without** the WS_VISIBLE flag such as:

```
HWND hCtl = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_STATIC, L"some text",
                           WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY, // no WS_VISIBLE flag
                           0, 0, 0, 0, hWndParent, (HMENU)IDC_STATIC1, g_hInst, 0);
```

Is there a more straightforward way to make it visible than the following?

```
void make_visible(HWND hCtl, HWND hWndParent) {
    SetWindowLongPtr(hCtl, GWL_STYLE,
                     GetWindowLongPtr(hCtl, GWL_STYLE) | WS_VISIBLE);
    RECT rc{};
    GetClientRect(hCtl, &rc);
    MapWindowRect(hCtl, hWndParent, &rc);
    InvalidateRect(hWndParent, &rc, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(hWndParent);

    //ShowWindow(hCtl, SW_SHOW); // no use: does not update window
    //SetWindowPos(hCtl, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);   // no use: does not update window
}
```

Comment: ShowWindow() works on a top-level window.  SetWindowPos() with SWP_SHOWWINDOW works on a child control.

Comment: Did you mean to invalidate the control's client area only? That's what your code does. That's unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a child control visible, call `SetWindowPos` like this:

```
SetWindowPos(hCtl, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Your code to call `MapWindowRect`, `InvalidateRect`, `UpdateRect` etc. should be removed.

Perhaps the real problem you have is that you have created the static control with zero width and height.

Comment: I corrected the size to non-zero values when pointed out. It wasn't intended.

Comment: So, once you have done that, simply call `SetWindowPos` as I demonstrate, and that is all.

Comment: I let you know of the edit, so that maybe you too might want to consider editing out that part of your  answer. It was an unintended mistake on my part which unfortunately just dilutes the question.

Comment: I just answered the question as it was written. I don't think I need to spend more time keeping up with edits. You know how to show your window now.

Comment: Understood. I just thought it would be cleaner for others reading about this question. I appreciate your input.

Comment: I rolled back the question so that the rest of us don't have to edit to keep up.

Comment: That's one other solution indeed. :-) But with all due respect, I just would like to mention that I edited the OP because that mistake of mine just diverts attention from the actual question.

Comment: I get that, but the flip side is that having answers that don't match the question can also cause confusion. At least everything is consistent now. And the main thrust of the question is clear, the answer is simple and clear.

Comment: Also true. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to make a window visible is only the function [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx). There is no need dealing with flags and so on. Usually you use `SW_SHOW` as a parameter for a child window. Check the other values and use what you think is appropriate.

If the window has a visible rectangle and isn't covered by another window it will show up. Even UpdateWindow calls are not needed. The window will show up in the next paint cycle. If your control has a size of 0,0,0,0 (as it was created) it will never show up.

There is also a [ShowWindowAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633549(v=vs.85).aspx) function for the use if the window is on a different thread to avoid blocking.

BTW: I don't understand what you try with invalidating the parent window area. If there is a child window clipping (`WS_CLIPCHILDREN`) it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that you're explicitly setting the `WS_VISIBLE` style yourself and *then* calling `ShowWindow`, which confuses Windows into believing that the window is already visible and doesn't need to be repainted.

Just call `ShowWindow`.  [There should be no need to explicitly set `WS_VISIBLE` yourself](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100719-00/?p=13403/) because [`ShowWindow` already does it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx).  You should not need to forcibly repaint your control.

Additionally, if you find some need to explicitly invalidate your control, it should be sufficient to just do `InvalidateRect(hCtl, NULL)` and not bother with `GetClientRect` and `MapWindowRect`.